# Transformation of Random Variable $y=\arccos(x)$

Tags: probability-distributions

Given random variable $x$, which has a bounded $\arcsin(a,b)$ distribution.  I am trying to find the distribution $Y$ such that $y=\arccos(x)$.

My intuition tells me that $Y$ is an uniform$(\arccos(a),\arccos(b))$ distribution.  How do I go about proving this?  I have been trying transformation of random variables, but the function nor it's derivative are monotonic and single-valued so I'm not sure it applies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EDIT:  Looking closer at my problem, it is such that $-1 < a,b < 1$

Comment: Please add this vital detail to the question body via an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Claim is not valid. For example let $$X\sim ArcSin(5,8)$$. [Arcsine_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution)

so
$5<X<8$, so It claimed $$Arccos(X)\sim Uniform(ArcCos(5),ArcCos(8))$$

What is $ArcCos(5)$???!!!

let we choose $a$ and $b$ such that $-1<b*sin(U)+a<1$ and so $ArcCos(b*sin(U)+a)$ is defined. Folllowing R code show $ArcCos(b*sin(U)+a)$ does not follow uniform

```
 set.seed(1)
 U<-runif(100000,-pi,pi)
 X<-.1*sin(U)+.2
 plot(density(acos(X)))
```

[image]
Hint:
I think if $U\sim Uniform(-\pi,\pi)$ so $ArcCos(sin(U))\sim Uniform$.

I think the key is behind on the following relation

$$Arcsin(x)+Arccos(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

[Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions)

$U\sim Uniform(-\pi,\pi)$ so  $$X=\sin(U)\sim ArcSin(-1,1)$$ and $$Arcsin(X)\sim Uniform(-\pi, \pi)$$

[Arcsine_distribution#Related_distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution#Related_distributions)

so $$Arccos(X)=\frac{\pi}{2} -Arcsin(X)\sim ??$$

```
 set.seed(1)
 U<-runif(100000,-pi,pi)
 X<-sin(U)
 plot(density(acos(X)))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks.  Not sure if I'm fully following.  Using your variables above, let's define $Y=\beta X + \alpha$ ~ $ArcSin(\alpha-\beta,\alpha+\beta)$.  Therefore, my problem would be $$ArcCos(Y) = \frac{\pi}{2} - ArcSin(Y) = \frac{\pi}{2} - Arcsin(\beta X + \alpha)  = \frac{\pi}{2} - Arcsin(\beta sin(U) + \alpha)$$  Still not sure how to go from here?

Comment: $ArcCos(Y)$ and $Arcsin(Y)$ are defined when $-1\leq Y\leq 1$.what do you mean  when $ArcSin(\beta \sin(U) +\alpha)$. for example when $u=0$ and $\alpha=5$
, what does $ArcSin(\beta \sin(u) +\alpha)$ mean?